# JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.greetapp.domain.User`

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster

I'm using JHipster and I'm running the following curl command:

> POST/api/gang-users

with body:

```
{
    "role": "member",
    "gang": "3",
    "user": "1"
}
```

but I get the following error:

> JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of
>   `com.getgreetapp.greetapp.domain.User` (although at least one Creator
>   exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize
>   from String value ('1'); nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `com.getgreetapp.greetapp.domain.User` (although
>   at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory
>   method to deserialize from String value ('1')\n at [Source:
>   (PushbackInputStream); line: 4, column: 10] (through reference chain:
>   com.getgreetapp.greetapp.domain.GangUser[\"user\"])

GangUserResource `createGangUser`

```
@PostMapping("/gang-users")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<GangUser> createGangUser(@Valid @RequestBody GangUser gangUser) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save GangUser : {}", gangUser);
        if (gangUser.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new gangUser cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        User user = userRepository.findById(gangUser.getUser());
        GangUser result = gangUserRepository.save(gangUser);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/gang-users/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
```

GangUser

```
package com.getgreetapp.greetapp.domain;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A GangUser.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "gang_user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class GangUser implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "jhi_role", nullable = false)
    private String role;

    @ManyToOne
    private Gang gang;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public GangUser() {

    }

    public GangUser(String role, Gang gang, User user)
    {
        this.role = role;
        this.gang = gang;
        this.user = user;
    }

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public GangUser role(String role) {
        this.role = role;
        return this;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Gang getGang() {
        return gang;
    }

    public GangUser gang(Gang gang) {
        this.gang = gang;
        return this;
    }

    public void setGang(Gang gang) {
        this.gang = gang;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public GangUser user(User user) {
        this.user = user;
        return this;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        GangUser gangUser = (GangUser) o;
        if (gangUser.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), gangUser.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GangUser{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", role='" + getRole() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

User

```
package com.getgreetapp.greetapp.domain;

import com.getgreetapp.greetapp.config.Constants;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.time.Instant;

/**
 * A user.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_user")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Pattern(regexp = Constants.LOGIN_REGEX)
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @JsonIgnore
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 60, max = 60)
    @Column(name = "password_hash", length = 60, nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "first_name", length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Size(max = 50)
    @Column(name = "last_name", length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Email
    @Size(min = 5, max = 254)
    @Column(length = 254, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean activated = false;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 6)
    @Column(name = "lang_key", length = 6)
    private String langKey;

    @Size(max = 256)
    @Column(name = "image_url", length = 256)
    private String imageUrl;

    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "activation_key", length = 20)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String activationKey;

    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "reset_key", length = 20)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String resetKey;

    @Column(name = "reset_date")
    private Instant resetDate = null;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "jhi_user_authority",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_name", referencedColumnName = "name")})
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @BatchSize(size = 20)
    private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    // Lowercase the login before saving it in database
    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = StringUtils.lowerCase(login, Locale.ENGLISH);
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public boolean getActivated() {
        return activated;
    }

    public void setActivated(boolean activated) {
        this.activated = activated;
    }

    public String getActivationKey() {
        return activationKey;
    }

    public void setActivationKey(String activationKey) {
        this.activationKey = activationKey;
    }

    public String getResetKey() {
        return resetKey;
    }

    public void setResetKey(String resetKey) {
        this.resetKey = resetKey;
    }

    public Instant getResetDate() {
        return resetDate;
    }

    public void setResetDate(Instant resetDate) {
        this.resetDate = resetDate;
    }

    public String getLangKey() {
        return langKey;
    }

    public void setLangKey(String langKey) {
        this.langKey = langKey;
    }

    public Set<Authority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(Set<Authority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        User user = (User) o;
        return !(user.getId() == null || getId() == null) && Objects.equals(getId(), user.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
            "login='" + login + '\'' +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", imageUrl='" + imageUrl + '\'' +
            ", activated='" + activated + '\'' +
            ", langKey='" + langKey + '\'' +
            ", activationKey='" + activationKey + '\'' +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Gang

```
package com.getgreetapp.greetapp.domain;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * A Gang.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "gang")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Gang implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "longitude", precision = 10, scale = 2, nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal longitude;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "latitude", precision = 10, scale = 2, nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal latitude;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "membership_approval", nullable = false)
    private String membershipApproval;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "privacy", nullable = false)
    private String privacy;

    public Gang() {}

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Gang name(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Gang description(String description) {
        this.description = description;
        return this;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public BigDecimal getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public Gang longitude(BigDecimal longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
        return this;
    }

    public void setLongitude(BigDecimal longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public BigDecimal getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public Gang latitude(BigDecimal latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        return this;
    }

    public void setLatitude(BigDecimal latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getMembershipApproval() {
        return membershipApproval;
    }

    public Gang membershipApproval(String membershipApproval) {
        this.membershipApproval = membershipApproval;
        return this;
    }

    public void setMembershipApproval(String membershipApproval) {
        this.membershipApproval = membershipApproval;
    }

    public String getPrivacy() {
        return privacy;
    }

    public Gang privacy(String privacy) {
        this.privacy = privacy;
        return this;
    }

    public void setPrivacy(String privacy) {
        this.privacy = privacy;
    }
    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Gang gang = (Gang) o;
        if (gang.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), gang.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Gang{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", name='" + getName() + "'" +
            ", description='" + getDescription() + "'" +
            ", longitude=" + getLongitude() +
            ", latitude=" + getLatitude() +
            ", membershipApproval='" + getMembershipApproval() + "'" +
            ", privacy='" + getPrivacy() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my humble opinion, there are a couple of things to check.

First, it isn't recommended to use the same object to store data in your database and response a request. The data object could be GangUser, User and Gang, while the response objects GangUserApi, UserApi, and GangApi. With this approach, you'll be able to amend a layer without modifying another.

Second, your service is expecting a GangUser with a User inside. The same User Object that you use to store it in the database. You're just sending a String ("1") instead of an object there.

A quick solution could be modifying the JSON:

```
{
    "role": "member",
    "gang": "3",
    "user": {
        "id":"1"
    }
}
```

But I would like to know if you understand what was going on. That is more important than just give you a quick solution.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Could you explain more about `The data object could be GangUser, User and Gang, while the response objects GangUserApi, UserApi, and GangApi. With this approach, you'll be able to amend a layer without modifying another.`? I was going through the same situation as questioner but I didn't understand that part.

Comment: Sure. We're going to suppose you only have a User object which you use as a response in your service and as a model. So, that object contains the persistence and JSON annotations. Now, what is going to happen if you need to add more attributes to your response but you don't want to persist them? or if you want to persist more data without altering your response service?. Suppose that you have 2 clients consuming your services at that moment, are you going to change the response?. Having a User and UserApi gives you the possibility the work in both sides almost without interfere between them